# Angular Unit Test SpyOn giving me errors

Tags: typescript, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do the unit testing for services, I mocked the data and expecting some result but getting error
Below is my component ts file 
ts file

```
setPrefixSuffixDetails(): void {
    this.profileService.getPrefixSuffixDetails()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          if(data.body.prefixlist.length > 0) {
            this.prefixConfig.options = data.body.prefixlist;
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

Below is my 
Spec.ts File

```
providers: [{provide: ProfileService, useClass: ProfileStub}]

beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileBeneficiariesViewComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
        profileService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProfileService);
    });

    let data = {body:['prefixList']}
    it('should have a method to get details', () => {
    profileService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProfileService);

    spyOn(profileService, 'getPrefixSuffixDetails').and.callThrough();
             component.ngOnInit();
     expect(data.body).toContain([ 'prefixlist' ]);

 });
```

Error which I am getting is below

```
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for setPrefixSuffixDetails()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)


class ProfileStub {
        getPrefixSuffixDetails = function () {
            return Observable.of(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `this` keyword in `spyOn()`. You can directly access `profileService`.

```
it('should have a method to get details', () => {

   let response: {"body":{"prefixlist":["DEACON","DR","MISS","MR","MRS","MS","PASTOR","REV"],"suffixlist":["I","II","III","IV","Jr","Sr"]}};
   spyOn(profileService, 'setPrefixSuffixDetails').and.callThrough().and.
            returnValue(Observable.of(response));
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(response.body).toContain('prefixList');

});
```

That should resolve your `Object not found` error.

Comment: It didn't work man same error, I am not getting the Object not found error, it different error here

Comment: Then try component.profileService instead of this.profileService

Comment: why its saying couldnt find an object?

Comment: Can you show your full test spec file? And how are you mocking `ProfileStub`?

Comment: <input type="text" name="transferAmount" title="transferAmount" [(ngModel)]="contribution.amount.displayValue |currency:'USD':true"
                    (ngModelChange)="contribution.amount.displayValue=$event"/>

Answer (score 0):

Inject your dependency using `inject` from `@angular/core/testing`

Your spec file should be something like this

```
describe('ProfileBeneficiariesViewComponent', () => {
    let component: ProfileBeneficiariesViewComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture< ProfileBeneficiariesViewComponent >;
    let profileService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {provide: ProfileService, useClass: ProfileStub}
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileBeneficiariesViewComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    beforeEach(inject([ProfileService], s => {
        profileService = s;
    }));

    it('Do Your test', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```